# Событие загрузки шаблона ng-transclude, для подключения скрипта?

Tags: angularjs

Настраиваю модуль Angular-Wizard (https://github.com/mgonto/angular-wizard)

Он включает в себя директивы. С помощью них подгружается шаблон. 
Модуль я применяю для создания много-шаговой формы. Все прекрасно работает.

Но единственный нюанс. При загрузке страницы, директивы wizard, подтягивают свой шаблон. Так как я использую его для создания форм, мне нужно подключить input mask.

```
<form id="s_add_agent_form" class="uk-form-stacked">
    <wizard on-finish="finishedWizard()" template="app/templates/wizard.tpl.html">
        <wz-step title="1" template="app/templates/wizard.step.tpl.html">
            <label for="user_phone1">Телефон</label>
            <input data-inputmask="'mask': '+7 (999) 999 99 99'" data-inputmask-showmaskonhover="false" type="text" class="masked_input md-input" name="user_phone1" id="user_phone1" md-input ng-model="s_user_data.step1.user_phone1" />
        </wz-step>
        <wz-step title="2" template="app/templates/wizard.step.tpl.html">
            <label for="user_phone2">Доп. телефон</label>
            <input data-inputmask="'mask': '+7 (999) 999 99 99'" data-inputmask-showmaskonhover="false" type="text" class="masked_input md-input" name="user_phone2" id="user_phone2" md-input ng-model="s_user_data.step1.user_phone2" />
        </wz-step>
        <wz-step title="3" template="app/templates/wizard.step.tpl.html">
            <label for="user_phone3">Доп. телефон</label>
            <input data-inputmask="'mask': '+7 (999) 999 99 99'" data-inputmask-showmaskonhover="false" type="text" class="masked_input md-input" name="user_phone3" id="user_phone3" md-input ng-model="s_user_data.step1.user_phone2" />
        </wz-step>
    </wizard>
</form>
```

Вот как выглядят шаблоны:
wizard.tpl.html

```
<div class="wizard">
    <div class="steps uk-clearfix">
        <ul ng-if="!hideIndicators" class="uk-clearfix">
            <li ng-class="{ default: !step.completed && !step.selected, current: step.selected && !step.completed, done: step.completed && !step.selected, editing: step.selected && step.completed, last: $last}" ng-repeat="step in getEnabledSteps()">
                <a ng-click="goTo(step)">
                    <span class="number">{{$index+1}}</span>
                    <span class="title">{{step.title || step.wzTitle}}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content" ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

wizard.step.tpl.html

```
<section ng-show="selected" ng-class="{current: selected, done: completed}" class="step body" ng-transclude>
</section>
```

**Вопрос:**
В момент инициализации контроллера содержимого формы еще нет.
Как мне в контроллере получить доступ к содержимому подгружаемых шаблонов? Для того чтобы выполнить например:

```
$maskedInput = $('.masked_input');
if($maskedInput.length) {
    $maskedInput.inputmask();
}
```

На данный момент решаю эту проблему с помощью $timeout:

```
$timeout(function(){
    $maskedInput = $('.masked_input');
    if($maskedInput.length) {
        $maskedInput.inputmask();
    }
}, 1);
```

Но понимаю что это не правильно. Как найти верный способ?

Comment: можете пример на [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Можно придумать такой хак:

Вы создаете кастомную директиву, которая при загрузке будет рассылать уведомление, что она загрузилась. Вставите ее в нужный вам шаблон, и получите событие, по которому форма уже будет существовать.

Создаем директиву:

```
youModule.directive('ngTplIsReady', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function($scope, $element, attrs) {
            $scope.$root.$broadcast('tpl_is_ready');
        }
    }
});
```

Вставляем в шаблон формы `<div data-ng-tpl-is-ready></div>`

В контролере слушаете событие от директивы:

```
$scope.$on('tpl_is_ready', function(e) {
    // Можно навешивать маски на инпуты
});
```